# How is it that a parameter reverts to its previous value after returning from a recursive function call?

Tags: javascript, function, recursion

I am relatively new to JavaScript and i can't wrap around my head on how this code is executing

```js
function foo(i) {
  if (i < 0) {
    return;
  }
  console.log(`begin: ${i}`);
  foo(i - 1);
  console.log(`end: ${i}`);
}
foo(3);
```

the output of this code is

```text
begin: 3
begin: 2
begin: 1
begin: 0
end: 0
end: 1
end: 2
end: 3
```

According to my understanding after all logs of begin statement, only one log with end statement should get printed that too with -1 value

```text
begin: 3
begin: 2
begin: 1
begin: 0
end: -1
```

As I gets decremented from `0` by `-1`, the if statement condition becomes true and returns the flow to next line of recursive function and prints end: `-1` and ends the program.
I have an intuition that this might be a silly question but I still want to know where am I lacking. Help would be appreciated

Comment: The program flow must return to the next line after every function call.

Comment: Recursion builds a stack, so: first-in, last-out. Since the first print statement occurs before the recursion, you are moving down. Opposite, the last occurs after, so you are moving back up... Think of the "end" message as a clean-up condition, after you reach zero,

Comment: Learn how to use breakpoints and step, and debug your own code-flow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call a function, you don't enter that function's definition. You enter that function definition's *copy*.

Each *invocation* of a function is *separate*. It doesn't matter what's the name of that function. Whether it's the same name of some other name -- each invocation is *new*. It *copies* the corresponding definition, and works on the *fresh copy*.

Imagine you call `foo(1)` in your example. Then your snippet is *the same as*

```
function foo1(i1) { // i1 here is 1
  if (i1 < 0) {
    return;
  }
  console.log(`begin: ${i1}`);
  foo0(i1 - 1);
  console.log(`end: ${i1}`);
}
function foo0(i0) {  // i0 here is 0
  if (i0 < 0) {
    return;
  }
  console.log(`begin: ${i0}`);
  foo_1(i0 - 1);
  console.log(`end: ${i0}`);
}
function foo_1(i_1) {  // i_1 here is -1
  if (i_1 < 0) {
    return;        // return is called
  }
  console.log(`begin: ${i_1}`);   // these lines
  foo_2(i_1 - 1);                 // are not
  console.log(`end: ${i_1}`);     //   executed
}
foo1(1);
```

You are probably not surprised that these `i_nnn`s in these different functions do not interfere with each other. But it's the same thing even with the same function `foo` called everywhere instead of these `foo_nnn`s. Because each call to `foo` copies the same definition and works on the new, fresh copy of it, as if it got a new name `foo_nnn` like here above, working on its own set of its inner variables `i_nnn`.

So then it is non-surprising that the above execution proceeds as

```
foo1(1);
```

which is

```
//foo1(1):
  ///// i1==1 ////
  if (i1 < 0) { return; }       // i1==1
  console.log(`begin: ${i1}`);  // i1==1
  foo0(i1 - 1);
  // function foo1 continues
  console.log(`end: ${i1}`);    // i1==1
  // end of function foo1
```

and this is the same as

```
//foo1(1):
  //// i1==1 ////
  if (i1 < 0) { return; }       // i1==1 ; 1<0 is false
  console.log(`begin: ${i1}`);  // i1==1
  //foo0(0):
          //// i0==0 ////
          if (i0 < 0) { return; }       // i0==0 ; 0<0 is false
          console.log(`begin: ${i0}`);  // i0==0
          foo_1(-1);
          // function foo0 continues
          console.log(`begin: ${i0}`);  // i0==0
          // end of function foo0
  // function foo1 continues
  console.log(`end: ${i1}`);    // i1==1
  // end of function foo1
```

and this is the same as

```
//foo1(1):
  //// i1==1 ////
  if (i1 < 0) { return; }       // i1==1 ; 1<0 is false
  console.log(`begin: ${i1}`);  // i1==1
  //foo0(0):
          //// i0==0 ////
          if (i0 < 0) { return; }       // i0==0 ; 0<0 is false
          console.log(`begin: ${i0}`);  // i0==0
          //foo_1(-1):
                  //// i_1== -1 ////
                  if (i_1 < 0) { return; }   // i_1== -1 ; -1<0 is true
                  // the function foo_1 is exited i.e.
                  //    nothing is printed and no more calls are made
                  // end of function foo_1
          // function foo0 continues
          console.log(`begin: ${i0}`);  // i0==0
          // end of function foo0
  // function foo1 continues
  console.log(`end: ${i1}`);    // i1==1
  // end of function foo1
```

Now, replace all `foo_nnn` in the above with `foo`.

Nothing changes.

Answer (score 0):

`i` is not decremented, the value `i-1` is passed as the value when `foo` is recursively called. When the value passed into `foo` is -1, it returns before anything is console logged, and goes up a level to where `i` is 0.

`` console.log(`end: ${i}`); `` prints out that value, and then the function implicitly returns up to the next level where `i` is 1. And so on from there.

Comment: But how does recursive function gets called after return throws flow to next line of recursive function(i.e after end : 0)

Comment: @Shubham the function doesn't get called again, but each invocation of the function has to finish its process.

Comment: Glad to help and that it makes sense now.

Answer (score -1):

The flow is like this

```
   Foo(3)
      Begin 3
      Foo(2)
        Begin 2
        Foo(1)
          Begin 1
          Foo(0)
            Begin 0
            Foo(-1) returns
            End 0
          End 1
        End 2
      End 3
```