# Recursive approach with and without manual backtracking

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, backtracking, recursive-backtracking

In some cases, like the "hasPathSum" problem, where we are checking for a specific condition (e.g., `targetSum == 0`) at leaf nodes, we don't need manual backtracking. The recursion naturally backtracks as it reaches the leaf nodes, and the state is automatically maintained correctly.

```
class Solution {
    public boolean hasPathSum(TreeNode root, int targetSum) {
        if (root == null) return false;
        if (root.left == null && root.right == null 
                              && targetSum == root.val) 
             return true;
        return hasPathSum(root.left, targetSum - root.val) 
                || hasPathSum(root.right, targetSum - root.val);
    }
}
```

Same problem,In such cases, we need to manually backtrack to the previous state when moving back up the recursive calls.

```
class Solution {
    int count = 0;

    public int pathSum(TreeNode root, int targetSum) {
        if (root == null) return 0;
        dfs(root, targetSum);
        return count;
    }

    public void dfs(TreeNode node, int targetSum) {
        if (node == null) return;

        targetSum -= node.val;
        if (targetSum == 0) {
            count++;
        }

        dfs(node.left, targetSum);
        dfs(node.right, targetSum);

        targetSum += node.val; // Backtrack, restore the previous state
    }
}
```

I don't understand how the values of parameters are passed in recursion, and why manual backtracking is needed when using the `targetSum` variable. Please help.

Comment: A [description of the "path sum" problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/path-sum/) can be found at LeetCode 112.

Comment: There is no need to update `targetSum` at the end -- it is at its end-of-life: no-one cares anymore what its value is. What you call "manual" backtracking is not needed in the second case either.

Comment: 1.if (node.right != null) {
    if (traversal(node.right, count - node.right.val) return true; 
}
2.if (node.right != null) { 
    count -= count.right.val;
    if (traversal(node.right, count)) return true;
    count += count.right.val
}
how about these?

Comment: Is that a follow up question? Either edit your question, or ask a new question.

Comment: regarding arguments, see e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76009361/849891) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46613542/849891).

Answer (score 0):

You need to manually undo any changes that you make to some *external*, global variable's value, before making the *next attempt's* change to the same value, because it is *the same entity* used by all calls.

One example is backtracking search for e.g. [Sudoku solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65361096/849891), maintaining one global 9x9 matrix. Another is producing [all permutations](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49907365/849891) of elements of a list. Yet another might be 8 Queens problem in chess, with 8x8 board.

If you pass that value's *copy* to each recursive invocation as one of its arguments, then the previous one remains unchanged and you need no manual undoing. But it can result in heavier memory usage, naturally.